# Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 32, 3], expected input[1, 9999, 5024] to have 32 channels, but got 9999 channels instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a cnn with `pytorch`. My error message I'm getting is:

> Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 32, 3], expected input[1, 9999, 5024] to have 32 channels, but got 9999 channels instead

Before starting to train my architecture I hand in my data and label to the

```
images_batch = torch.from_numpy(np.array(X))
labels_batch = torch.from_numpy(np.array(y))

dataset_train = TensorDataset(X, y)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset_train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
```

The dimension of X is `(5024, 9999, 1)` with 5024 being the number of instances, 9999 the sequence length. The dimension to y is `(5024,1)`.

My current code for the model is the following:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(32, 8, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv1d(8, 16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv1d(16, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=0)
        #self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32, 2)

    def forward(self, X):
        X = F.relu(self.conv1(X))
        X = F.relu(self.conv2(X))
        X = F.max_pool2d(X,2)
        X = self.conv3(X)
        X = F.max_pool2d(X,2)
        #X = self.fc1(X)
        return F.softmax(X,dim =1)
    

device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'


model = Model().to('cpu')

# loss and optimizer
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)


def check_accuracy(loader, model):
    num_correct = 0
    num_samples = 0
    model.eval()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        for x,y in loader:
            x = x.to(device=device)
            y = y.to(device=device)
            
            scores = model(x)
            _, predictions = scores.max(1)
            num_correct += (predictions == y).sum()
            num_samples += predictions.size(0)

        print(
            f"Got {num_correct} / {num_samples} with accuracy"
            f" {float(num_correct) / float(num_samples) * 100:.2f}"
        )

    model.train()
            
            
            
check_accuracy(train_loader, model)




for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
        data.to(device=device)
        targets.to(device=device)
        
        data = data.reshape(data[0],1)
        
        
        scores = model(data)
        loss = criterion(scores, targets)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        
        optimizer.step()
```

I'm aware that in tensorflow the ordering of the tensor is different than in pytorch.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "The dimension of X is (5024, 9999, 1) with 5024 being the number of instances, 9999 the sequence length. The dimension to y is (5024,1)." Okay, so what does this tell you about the size of the weights that the network should have? Do you *understand* the error message? What actually is the *question*? Please read [ask], and **ask** a question.

Comment: Yes I understand the error message. According to pytorch the dimension are given by `N,C,L` where N are my batch size, C my channels and L the length to the sequence. Thats also where I see my error. However when I do so I get problems in creating my dataset via `TensorDataset` and `DataLoader`. My question now is if it's a reshaping problem or a problem a model itself.

Comment: That sounds like a question better suited to [ai.se], then.

Comment: Your sequence’s channel is 5024 with length 9999, so the conv1d should has num channel 5024 instead of 32, just like the message

Comment: Thank you thats what i did, however, the error message remains.